# Javascript: How to download zip from API server via Firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, blob, fetch

Currently, I have implemented the following and it works on the Chrome browser. But on the Firefox browser, it gets the response from the API server, but nothing is being downloaded to the Firefox browser.

What could I be doing wrong? Is the following not cross-platform compatible?

Thank you in advance

Here is the code:

```
var config = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify(...)
}

fetch("https://test-server.com:8080/download/zip", config)
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(zipFile => {
        console.log(zipFile)

        var blob = zipFile;
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = 'download'
        link.click();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error: ", error)
      })
```

On Chrome, `console.log(zipFile)` would log something like: `Blob {size: 504188, type: "application/zip"}` but on Firefox, it logs `Blob {size: 504188, type: "" }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because the link element isn't attached to the body?

When I tried the following it worked in Chrome but not Firefox (like you're experiencing):

```
link = document.createElement('a')
link.href = 'http://google.com'
link.click()
```

but

```
link = document.createElement('a')
link.href = 'http://google.com'
document.body.appendChild(link)
link.click()
```

worked in Firefox as well.

Comment: Would the following be the right way to do as you suggested? `var blob = zipFile;
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);    document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.download = 'download'
        link.click();`

Comment: Pretty much (missing some semicolons though, if doing it on a single line, eg `var link = document.createElement('a'); link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); document.body.appendChild(link); link.download = 'download'; link.click();`)

Comment: Eg, in FF, this works for me: `var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({hello: "world"}, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json'}); var link = document.createElement('a'); link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); document.body.appendChild(link); link.download = 'download'; link.click();` (I get the download prompt, and the result of which is the hello world JSON.)

Comment: Quick JS bin (that works for me in FF): http://jsbin.com/cihigarume/edit?html,js,output (and when the `document.body.appendChild(link);` is commented it fails in FF (for me))

Comment: but doing `document.body.appendChild(link);` works for both Chrome and FF?

Comment: Adding the `document.body.appendChild(link);` works in both, yes (it just means that the `a` is added to the DOM somewhere (of note, you might want to hide it, eg `link.style.display = 'none';`))

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify on what you mean by `a` is added to the DOM? Also where would I need to place `link.style.display='none';`?

Comment: Eg `var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({hello: "world"}, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json'}); var link = document.createElement('a'); link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); link.download = 'download'; link.style.display = 'none';  document.body.appendChild(link); link.click();`. Basically the `a` needs to be "added to the webpage" (the simplest way I can think to word it) before it can be clicked (in FF,it seems). MDN has an overview of what the DOM is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction (it's basically what you're working with)

Comment: Firefox downloads the file but why does it as a `blob resource` and not zip even though it is a zip file? I would have to manually append .zip to the file and open it up that way. Chrome downloads it as a zip though.

Comment: Checking in to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: Hi, I don't quite understand what the issue you're now encountering is? For me, in FF, these both download the zip: http://jsbin.com/puxiluyune/1/edit?html,js,output and an alternative as I'm not quite certain what you're trying to achieve (I don't think there's any real difference?): http://jsbin.com/nelozocare/1/edit?html,js,output  (I just picked a random zip off github)

Comment: Oh, was the issue just that the file was called `download`? That's just the `a`'s download attribute, ie `link.download = 'filename.zip'` _might_ be what you're after? :-s

Comment: how is it that Chrome recognizes that the blob is a zip, so adds `.zip` after? Whereas Firefox just downloads it as is exactly? Would defining `filename.zip` make Chrome download a file like `filename.zip.zip` then?

Comment: I'm assuming/guessing that Chrome and FF infer different things from the response headers and/or from inspecting the file contents to determine the mime type? Maybe? Not sure, but I tried the jsbin in Chrome and got `file.zip` -- the same as FF.

Comment: Awesome, it downloads on FF! One last thing, on the FF browser it tells me it's a blob before downloading onto the browser. Is there a way around it or how can I download it directly as a zip folder that is coming from server? Thanks again Bryce

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's possible, looks  like it's a limitation in FF: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1101598

Comment: thank you so much for all the help. Just accepted and upvoted the answer. Appreciate it again!